# With two seperate licences, can I switch from Windows 10 to 7 and back to 10 again?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, license-key

I have two valid licence keys for Windows:

- **Key A** - originally Windows 7, but upgraded to Windows 10
- **Key B** - not yet activated for Windows 7

I'm running Windows 10 with key A now.

My plan is to format the HDD, re-install Windows 7 and activate key B.

Am I right in thinking that, in the future, if I format the HDD again and install Windows 10 - then the online activation process will pick up on the fact that I previously used key A and I'll be fully activated?

Comment: You can run any combination of Windows you want provided you have the licenses for it.  If you upgraded a license to Windows 10, you can use it to run, Windows 7 or Windows 10.  Once activated on a machine, Windows 10 will automatically activate, on that machine for its lifespan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on if you have a retail key or OEM (Original Equipment manufacturer) key. [Source](http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/software/operating-systems/1403593/how-to-upgrade-to-windows-10-and-get-your-new-licence-key)

If you have an OEM key (A laptop will come with one, or you can buy them yourself) Then you are entitled to reinstall windows 10 using that key.

> Confirmation from Microsoft: "If a customer has already taken the upgrade, they will be able to clean install back to Windows 10 because their device will have been provisioned with the new store-based licence."

However if you bought a retail copy then you can only transfer windows 10 during the upgrade offer. After that you will need to buy windows 10.

Comment: I had a Windows 7 retail key, and upgraded to Windows 10. I then downgraded to Windows 7, but it says that my copy of Win 10 is "reserved". Does that last bit address the OP's situation?

Comment: Most likely yes, but it depends if the key is OEM or retail. If the key is retail then yes it does. I don't know if there is a grace period for the reservation, but by the sound of the source retail users are on a limited time frame.

Comment: Key A (the one upgraded to Windows 10) is OEM and key B (the one for Windows 7 but not yet activated) is a retail. It sounds like the only thing I need to research (when I come to re-install Windows 10) is whether or not I can just use the ISO downloaded from Microsoft given that it's activated on an OEM key.